# Результаты опроса разработчиков Stack Overflow 2016

Tags: поддержка

> ## Введение
>
> В этом году более пяти тысяч разработчиков поделились с нами
>   информацией о том, где и над чем они работают, кто они и какие они.
>   Сейчас вы прочтете результаты самого полного в истории исследования,
>   посвященного личности современного программиста.

Приблизительно каждые 8 секунд на Stack Overflow появляется новый вопрос по программированию  В этом году на вопросы своих коллег по цеху ответили 56033 разработчиков из 173 стран мира.

Мы задали им 45 вопросов. Результаты кратко: программисты любят Rust. Даже разработчики серверной части веб-приложений владеют JavaScript. Только 7% программистов считают себя «рок-звёздами». Большинство программистов (за исключением разработчиков из Германии) любят собак больше, чем кошек.

Опрос несовершенен. Хотя нам удалось произвести огромный срез мнений, позволяющий выделить некоторые закономерности, наше исследование можно назвать предвзятым в отношении разработчиков, не говорящих на английском языке, а также тех, кто не испытывает особого желания заполнять англоязычные опросники.

В некоторых разделах мы откорректировали результаты с учетом данных, полученных из анализа активности посетителей Stack Overflow – а это 40 млн. визитов в месяц.

Описывая результаты опроса, мы будем использовать определения «программисты», «разработчики» и «респонденты», эти термины взаимозаменяемы. Кроме того, мы будем ставить запятые вне кавычек, как это делают разработчики.

Comment: Не прошло и полгода )

Comment: А графики остались без перевода

Comment: @Qwertiy Да, к сожалению. В следующем году постараюсь сделать лучше.

Comment: Зря только на ответы разбили, порядок нарушается. Лучше бы всё дать в теле вопроса. По факту перевода - респект!

Comment: @KromStern Так и было, но, оказывается, у тела вопроса есть ограничение на количество символов, в которое я не попал на треть.

Answer (score 6):

> ## Работа
>
> На работе разработчики хотят учиться, заинтересованы в поддержании баланса труда и отдыха, а также небезразличны к уровню трудовой компенсации. Но, главное – разработчики хотят писать код.

### I. Рабочий статус

- 67.8% Полная ставка
- 12.6% Студент
- 7.1% Фрилансер/Работа по контракту
- 4.3% Работа «на себя» (частный предприниматель)
- 3.5% Неполная ставка
- 1.8% Другое
- 1.8% Безработный
- 0.8% Предпочитаю не отвечать
- 0.2% На пенсии

Подавляющее большинство разработчиков трудоустроены. 91% разработчиков мира имеют оплачиваемую работу  (на полную ставку, в качестве индивидуального предпринимателя или удаленно).

### II. Поиск работы

[image: Looking for a Job]

Только 15% разработчиков активно ищут работу, но 78% заинтересованы в получении информации о новых вакансиях.

Если вы – работодатель, нам хотелось бы узнать, что вы предпринимаете, чтобы войти в контакт с разработчиками, [которые не ведут активных поисков работы](http://business.stackoverflow.com/?ref=survey-2016).

#### Кто ищет работу?

[image: Who's looking]

[image: Not Looking]

В США наиболее активно ищут работу студенты, аналитики и тестировщики. Дизайнеры, руководящий состав и специалисты по машинному обучению наименее заинтересованы в получении предложений от работодателей.

### III. Как находят работу?

- 28.3% Меня рекомендовал друг
- 17.2% Другой веб-сайт
- 13.8% Независимый рекрутер
- 9.8% Я хотел работать в этой компании и искал вакансию специально
- 9.5% Рекрутер целевой компании
- 6.3% Ярмарка вакансий
- 6.0% Работаю на себя (я сам создал вакансию для себя)
- 5.6% Другое
- 2.8% Stack Overflow
- 0.4% Twitter
- 0.3% Facebook

В большинстве стран (кроме Индии) самый распространенный способ трудоустройства – по рекомендациям друзей.

### IV. Приоритеты в работе

- 62.7% Заработная плата
- 50.4% Поддержание комфортного режима труда и отдыха
- 41.8% Корпоративная культура
- 39.9% Профессиональный и личностный уровень коллег по работе
- 37.1% Гибкий график работы
- 35.9% Создание важного, значимого продукта
- 31.2% Создание инновационного продукта
- 30.3% Местонахождение офисных помещений
- 29.1% Техническое обеспечение компании
- 28.7% Возможность карьерного роста
- 24.5% Возможность удаленной работы
- 20.1% Возможность принимать решения или влиять на принятие решений
- 17.1% Репутация компании
- 10.4% Наличие медстраховки
- 9.1% Отрасль
- 7.8% Размер компании
- 7.3% Название должности
- 6.4% Финансовое состояние компании, положение на рынке
- 6.2% Равенство
- 4.2% Стадия развития компании
- 3.0% Другое

При рассмотрении вакансии, зарплата – один из факторов, которые учитывают большинство разработчиков, но это не обязательно самый важный фактор в процессе выбора места работы. 37% разработчиков вообще не включили зарплату в число своих приоритетов.

Интересно, что немецкие разработчики проявляют меньший интерес к зарплатному вопросу, чем разработчики из других стран. Разработчики США и Франции придают меньшее значение возможности продвижения по службе, британцев больше интересует вопрос географического расположения места работы, а программисты из Индии больше ценят гибкий график, причастность к созданию инновационного продукта, возможность удаленной работы и придают значение названию должности.

#### Приоритеты в зависимости от должности

[image: Full Stack Priority]

[image: Executive Priority]

[image: QA Priority]

[image: Students Priority]

Разработчики различных специализаций имеют разные приоритеты. Разработчики полного цикла придают больше значения рабочей технологии.

Разработчики-руководители придают меньше значения балансу между трудом и отдыхом. Больше их заботит возможность создавать значимый продукт, способность влиять на решения, а также то, что не упомянули разработчики других специализаций: равенство.

Специалисты по машинному обучению хотят создавать инновационный продукт.

Специалисты по тестированию ПО более, чем кто-либо, чувствительны к личностным и профессиональным качествам коллег и корпоративной культуре компании.

#### Приоритеты меняются в зависимости от опыта

[image: Changing trends]

По мере того, как разработчики нарабатывают опыт, возможность принятия самостоятельных решений приобретает для них все больший приоритет; аналогичная картина наблюдается с возможностью удаленной работы (мы говорили вам, что обожаем удаленную работу?). Молодые разработчики более увлечены идеей создания чего-то нового – они хотят изменить мир.

#### В некоторых странах размер оплаты труда играет более важную роль

[image: Money matter]

<sub>Учитывались ответы разработчиков с опытом работы более 5 лет из стран, представленных более чем 200 респондентами.</sub>

Разработчики склонны придавать большое значение величине зарплаты в странах со сравнительно низким уровнем зарплат разработчиков. Разработчики из Скандинавских стран придают даже меньшее значение уровню зарплаты, чем предполагает этот тренд.

### V. Программисты любят учиться

[image: Learn Global]

После того, как разработчик находит работу, он хочет учиться новому и творить. Для разработчиков Индии повышение по службе имеет более высокий приоритет, чем для разработчиков из других стран.

### VI. Осложнения на рабочем месте

- 34.9% Нереалистичные сроки
- 34.7% Плохая документация
- 33.5% Отсутствие требований
- 30.3% Неэффективные процессы разработки
- 29.6% Слабая кодовая база
- 28.1% Изменяющиеся требования
- 24.8% Устаревшие технологии
- 22.9% Ограниченные ресурсы
- 22.3% Слабая команда
- 22.1% Не техническое руководство
- 20.4% Необходимость взаимодействия с необразованными людьми
- 18.2% Плохое расписание работы
- 17.4% Корпоративная политика
- 14.9% Необходимость взаимодействия с не техническим персоналом
- 11.9% Плохая инфраструктура
- 8.2% Необходимость быть вежливым

Самыми раздражающими факторами для разработчиков стали: неоправданные ожидания, плохая документация и неточно сформулированные технические задания. Знакомая картина?

#### С приходом опыта характер испытываемых трудностей меняется

[image: Experience changes]

Трудности, испытываемые более опытными разработчиками, отличаются от тех, которые досаждают их менее опытным коллегам. С накоплением опыта низкое качество документации становится все менее раздражающим, но большее огорчение вызывает отсутствие возможности менять кода. Кроме того, у опытных разработчиков возникает меньше трудностей со «стремлением быть вежливым» (вероятно, быть вежливыми они уже не пытаются…).

### VII. Заработная плата

#### Зарплата в зависимости от занимаемой должности

[image: Salary per Occupation]

<sub>Среди разработчиков с опытом работы более пяти лет</sub>

#### Покупательная способность в зависимости от страны проживания

[image: Big Mac Index]

<sub>Среди разработчиков с опытом работы более пяти лет в соответствии с «Биг Мак индексом» [по версии журнала «The Economist», 2016 г.](http://www.economist.com/content/big-mac-index)</sub>

«Биг Мак индекс» — отличный способ оценки покупательной способности жителей различных стран. В Южной Африке говядина (как и другие товары) имеет низкую стоимость, и среднестатистический разработчик может себе позволить более 25000 Биг Маков в год. Разработчики с опытом работы более 5 лет из США и Украины также не голодают.

#### Зарплата и стоимость аренды жилья в различных городах

[image: Salary vs rent cost]

<sub>Среди разработчиков с опытом работы более пяти лет. Apartment Price (стоимость квартиры) = стоимость аренды в USD двухкомнатной квартиры в центре города. Источник: [Numbeo](http://www.numbeo.com/cost-of-living/).</sub>

В Москве аренда жилья дьявольски дорога (чтобы жить в центре города, среднестатистическому разработчику придётся тратить на аренду квартиры более половины дохода). Разработчикам имеет смысл обратить внимание на Монреаль (Канада), Берлин (Германия), Пуну (Индия) или Бангалор (Индия)(который, к слову, дает Stack Overflow больший трафик, чем любой другой город мира). Остин, штат Техас, — лучший выбор для тех американских разработчиков, кто не собирается спустить на аренду жилья всю зарплату.
Все самые высокооплачиваемые рабочие места сосредоточены в Калифорнии (самые высокие зарплаты – в Пало-Альто, $153000 в год), а вне США – в Цюрихе (Швейцария), где среднестатистическая годовая зарплата программиста с опытом работы более 5 лет составляет $105000.

#### Зарплата в зависимости от размера компании

- 111.9% 10000+ сотрудников
- 105.6% 5000 – 9999 сотрудников
- 102.7% 1000 – 4999 сотрудников
- 98.7% 100 – 499 сотрудников
- 98.1% 500 – 999 сотрудников
- 92.5% 20 – 99 сотрудников
- 87.7% 10 – 19 сотрудников
- 85.7% 5 – 9 сотрудников
- 93.0% 1 – 4 сотрудника

Размер среднестатистической зарплаты растет с увеличением размеров компании. Но, похоже, и в небольших компаниях платят совсем не плохо.

#### Компенсация в зависимости от удовлетворенностью работой

[image: Happiness]

В целом, прослеживается четкая корреляция между компенсацией и удовлетворенностью работой. Можно ли купить счастье за деньги? Вполне – в некоторых случаях. Скорее всего, высокооплачиваемые разработчики имеют более богатый выбор на рынке труда и поэтому могут подбирать место по своему вкусу, что изначально повышает вероятность большей удовлетворенности работой.

#### Компенсация в зависимости от вида трудоустройства

- $98949 Полный рабочий день
- $92311 По контракту/фрилансер
- $82293 Индивидуальный предприниматель
- $55000 Другое
- $47389 Безработный
- $45454 Пенсионер
- $41629 Частичная занятость

Разработчики, работающие на полную ставку, превалируют (их доля около 85%), получая в среднем более высокую зарплату, чем фрилансеры или индивидуальные предприниматели (но последние с большей вероятностью будут любить свою работу). Какова разница в зарплатах частного предпринимателя и фрилансера/контрактника? Около $10000 в год.

#### Компенсация в зависимости от пола

[image: Age Men vs Women]

[image: Experience Men vs Women]

Для молодых разработчиков из США не прослеживается сколь-либо заметного различия в уровне зарплат, но с увеличением возраста до 30 и более лет разница в зарплатах мужчин и женщин составляет около $20000 в год. Эта разница менее выражена, если проанализировать количество лет работы разработчиков обоего пола.

#### Компенсация в зависимости от образования

[image: Salary by Education]

<sub>На основе ответов 20001 разработчика с опытом работы более пяти лет</sub>

Во всемирных масштабах, разработчики со степенью магистра имеют наивысшую среднюю зарплату. Более высокую зарплату получают те, кто прошел отраслевую сертификацию(-и) или имеет научную степень (PhD).

### VIII. Компании

#### Индустрия

[image: Industry]

[image: Job Satisfaction]

Самое большое число разработчиков работает в индустрии разработки ПО. Программирование прочно вошло и в несколько тысяч «других» отраслей (прежде всего, в страхование, исследовательскую деятельность, индустрию путешествий, энергетику). Разработчики, которые трудятся на ниве создания компьютерных игр, с большей вероятностью будут любить свою работу, чем те, кто занят в других отраслях.

Разработчики, работающие на промышленном производстве и в финансовой сфере, рассказали, что им постоянно приходится иметь дело с унаследованным кодом. Разработчики из оборонной сферы любят свое начальство, а также чаще других имеют на своем железе ПО слежения за действиями пользователя. Совпадение?..

#### Размер компании

- 22.0% 20 – 99 Сотрудников
- 17.4% 100 – 499 Сотрудников
- 12.0% 10000+ Сотрудников
- 10.2% 10 – 19 Сотрудников
- 9.5% 1 – 4 Сотрудника
- 9.2% 1000 – 4999 Сотрудников
- 7.8% 5 – 9 Сотрудников
- 5.9% 500 – 999 Сотрудников
- 3.5% 5000 – 9999 Сотрудников
- 2.6% Я не работаю в компании

В отношении численности сотрудников в компании-работодателе ответы разделились поровну: половина респондентов работает в компаниях с числом сотрудников меньше 100, половина – с числом сотрудников более 100 человек. Около 25% ответивших работают в компаниях с коллективом, насчитывающим свыше 1000 сотрудников.

### IX. Команда

[image: Team By Dev Type]

[image: Lone Wolfs]

Разработчик-одиночка – это миф (либо большая редкость). 96% разработчиков сообщили, что работают в команде.

Разработчики, которые менее всего соответствовали традиционному образу разработчика, чаще отвечали, что работают в гордом одиночестве. Специалисты по контролю качества, наоборот, с меньшей вероятностью оказывались «одинокими волками».

#### Девушки в команде

Верхняя часть

- 29.4% Аналитик
- 28.8% Научный сотрудник
- 27.5% Дизайнер
- 25.5% Администратор баз данных
- 25.1% Инженер по качеству

Нижняя часть

- 14.2% Разработчик встраиваемых систем
- 16.9% Разработчик
- 17.2% DevOps
- 17.3% Системный администратор
- 18.2% Разработчик серверной части

<sub>На основе 45 561 ответ (только мужчины)</sub>

Мы спрашивали участников опроса о размере их команд и количестве женщин в их составе. Вышеприведенные данные составлены на основе ответов разработчиков–мужчин. Больший процент сотрудников женского пола наблюдается у аналитиков и специалистов по обработке данных (не показано: в составе команд специалистов по контролю качества, в среднем, присутствует две женщины – самый высокий показатель среди всех специализаций). Разработчики встраиваемых и приложений для ПК имеют самый низкий процент сотрудниц в команде.

### X. Удаленная работа

- 48.4% Крайне редко работаю удаленно
- 22.0% Никогда
- 17.6% Частично работаю удаленно
- 12.1% Удаленно на полный рабочий день

Около 12% разработчиков работают удаленно на полную ставку. Всего удаленно работают 30% разработчиков.

#### Удаленно работающие разработчики имеют больший опыт

- 20.5% Менее года
- 19.8% 1 - 2 года
- 23.4% 2 – 5 лет
- 29.5% 6 – 10 лет
- 40.0% Более 11 лет

Разработчики с опытом работы более 11 лет почти в два раза чаще работают удаленно, чем те, опыт которых не превышает 5 лет.

#### Удаленна работа в странах

- 46.5% Аргентина
- 35.2% Мексика
- 33.7% США
- 33.0% Россия
- 32.9% Финляндия
- 30.8% Украина
- 30.2% Нидерланды
- 29.5% Польша
- 29.4% Испания
- 28.6% Южная Африка
- 28.3% Бразилия
- 28.0% Канада
- 27.1% Индия
- 26.9% Австралия
- 26.4% Италия
- 26.4% Швейцария
- 26.2% Дания
- 25.3% Британия
- 24.9% Германия
- 24.3% Швеция
- 24.3% Румыния
- 23.5% Франция

Аргентинские разработчики намного чаще работают удаленно, чем разработчики из других стран.

#### Работающие удаленно любят свою работу

- 44.5% Удаленно на полный рабочий день
- 35.7% Частично работаю удаленно
- 31.9% Крайне редко работаю удаленно
- 24.5% Никогда

<sub>Процент разработчиков, которые сказали, что любят свою работу</sub>

Разработчики работающие удаленно больше любят свою работу, чем те, кто работает из офиса. Вы работаете из дома? А хотели бы? [У нас есть масса предложений об удаленном трудоустройстве](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?allowsremote=true&ref=survey-2016) – убедитесь в этом сами.

### XI. Отправка кода на сервер

- 57.0% Несколько раз в день
- 17.7% Несколько раз в неделю
- 10.6% Один раз в день
- 5.9% Несколько раз в месяц
- 3.3% Я никогда не отправляю код на сервер
- 4.2% Я не отправляю код на сервер вообще, но достаточно часто обновляю конечный продукт
- 1.4% Другое

57% разработчиков ответили, что отправляют код на сервер и/или обновляют локальную кодовую базу по несколько раз в день.

#### Счастливее те, кто отправляет код на удаленный сервер

- 65.4% Я никогда не отправляю код на сервер
- 66.0% Несколько раз в месяц
- 71.3% Несколько раз в неделю
- 72.7% Один раз в день
- 76.5% Несколько раз в день

В целом, прослеживается явная корреляция между удовлетворенностью работой и частотой отправки изменений кода. Разработчики хотят писать код! Или, возможно, довольные жизнью разработчики вносят изменения чаще.

Answer (score 1):

> ## Профиль разработчика
>
> Кто пишет код? – Все большее число людей по всему миру.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В января 46 миллионов человек посетило Stack Overflow, 16 миллионов из числа них, по нашим оценкам, – профессиональные программисты.

Выводы о том, является ли участник профессиональным программистом, мы делали, исходя из того, что [читают и что делают](http://kevinmontrose.com/2015/01/27/providence-machine-learning-at-stack-exchange/) участники, когда заходят на Stack Overflow. Мы собираем данные об активности пользователей для того, чтобы предлагать вакансии, которые могли бы быть вам интересны, и вопросы, на которые вы, как мы думаем, сможете ответить. Вы можете [загрузить](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/prediction-data?ref=survey-2016) и изучить эти данные в любое время.

### II. Специализации разработчиков

- 28.0% Веб-разработчик полного цикла
- 12.2% Разработчик серверной части веб-приложений
- 11.4% Студент
- 8.4% Разработчик мобильных приложений (Android, iOS, WP, кроссплатформенные приложения)
- 6.9% Разработчик настольных приложений
- 5.8% Разработчик веб-интерфейсов
- 5.2% Другое
- 3.0% Разработчики услуг корпоративного уровня
- 2.6% Разработчик встраиваемых приложений
- 2.2% DevOps
- 1.9% Разработчики с образованием в сфере статистики и математики
- 1.8% Управленческий персонал (VP of Engineering, CTO, CIO, etc.)
- 1.6% Специалист по анализу данных
- 1.5% Системный администратор
- 1.4% Технический менеджер
- 1.2% Аналитик
- 0.1% Специалист по коммерческой разведке или хранению данных
- 0.1% Разработчик в сфере компьютерного обучения

<sub>На основе 49 525 ответов</sub>

Наибольшее число разработчиков считают себя разработчиками полного цикла. В среднем, разработчики полного цикла свободно пишут код на 5-6 основных языках или платформах (для сравнения, остальные владеют лишь четырьмя). Программисты руководящего звена владеют бóльшим числом языков и технологий, чем остальные, что, скорее всего, является результатом более обширного опыта.

Приблизительно равное число программистов (по 3%) назвали себя разработчиками мобильных приложений и разработчиками мобильных приложений под Android. Около 2,5% всех программистов создают мобильные приложения под iOS. 59 ответов мы получили от разработчиков мобильных приложений под Windows Phone.

#### Популярность технологий у разработчиков разных специализаций

[image: Full-Stack Devs' tech]

[image: Mobile Devs' tech]

[image: Students' tech]

JavaScript – самый распространенный язык программирования в мире. Даже разработчики серверной части предпочитают использовать именно его.

### III. Программисты, инженеры и разработчики

- 71.6% Разработчик
- 60.3% Программист
- 41.8% Инженер
- 28.3% Старший разработчик
- 26.8% Разработчик полного цикла
- 12.0% Другое
- 11.4% Хакер
- 11.2% Эксперт
- 9.8% Ниндзя
- 9.2% Менеджер
- 7.4% Рок-звезда
- 5.0% Гуру
- 4.2% Stack Overflow–разработчик

<sub>На основе 55 735 ответов</sub>

В этом году мы узнавали у респондентов, кто они: инженеры, эксперты, хакеры и т.д., используя описания, которые часто встречаются в объявлениях о трудоустройстве, визитных карточках и личном профиле Twitter.

95% респондентов считают себя разработчиками, программистами, инженерами, старшими разработчиками или разработчиками полного цикла. Разработчики встраиваемых приложений с большей вероятностью назовут себя инженерами. Программисты графики, скорее всего, назовут себя просто программистами. Но вариант «разработчик» лидирует с отрывом. Именно разработчиками считаем себя и мы.

#### Рок-звезды или ниндзя?

[image: Rock stars]

[image: Ninja]

10% респондентов назвали себя ниндзя. Но настоящие ниндзя никогда в этом не признаются: ведь они действуют тайно, подкрадываясь к жертве под покровом ночи и способствуя созданию «атмосферы неприязни на рабочем месте».

### IV. Возраст

[image: Возраст]

<sub>На основе 55 338 ответов</sub>

Возраст среднестатистического программиста – 29,6 лет. Медианный возраст по выборке – 27 лет.

### Зависимость среднего возраста программиста от страны проживания

- 32.0 Соединенные Штаты Америки
- 31.6 Италия
- 31.5 Австралия
- 31.4 Испания
- 31.1 Швеция
- 31.0 Британия
- 30.5 Канада
- 29.8 Германия
- 29.5 Нидерланды
- 29.1 Франция
- 27.7 Бразилия
- 26.7 Польша
- 26.6 Российская Федерация
- 25.5 Индия

<sub>На основе стран с более чем 1000 ответов</sub>

Среднестатистический разработчик в Индии на 6 лет моложе своего среднестатистического коллеги из США. Хотите знать, где искать программистов будущего? В Индии, *России*, Польше и Бразилии.

### V. Опыт работы

- 5.8% менее года
- 12.4% 1–2 года
- 23.2% 6–10 лет
- 26.5% более 11 лет
- 32.1% 2–5 лет

<sub>На основе 49 521 ответа</sub>

Среднестатистический разработчик имеет 6,5 лет опыта работы в IT. Это не обязательно *профессиональный* опыт (среднестатистический студент сообщает, что его/ее опыт работы в IT или программирования составляет 3,4 года). Программисты нарабатывают опыт в написании код, даже если работают на добровольных началах или неполный день. Приведенные выше результаты близки к статистике базы [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/why-jobs), содержащей резюме более 230 000 разработчиков.

Опыт работы среднестатистического разработчика пользовательских web-интерфейсов составляет 3,5 года, разработчика полного цикла – 8 лет, технического менеджера – 13 лет.

#### «Звездные войны» или «Звездный путь»

[image: Star Wars vs Star Trek]

<sub>На основе 42 503 отзывов</sub>

Как оказалось, с возрастом предпочтения меняются. Сорокалетние разработчики предпочитают «Звездные войны», пятидесятилетние –  «Звездный путь». Далее идут: сериал «Светлячок» («Firefly»), «Звездные врата» («Stargate»), «Доктор Кто» («Doctor Who») и «Вавилон-5» («Babylon 5»).

### VI. Пол

- 92.8% Мужчины
- 5.8% Женщины
- 0.5% Другое
- 1.0% Предпочитаю не отвечать

<sub>На основе 55 128 отзывов</sub>

Наше исследование демонстрирует резкий дисбаланс в количестве технических специалистов мужского и женского пола. На самом деле, как нам известно, число женщин-разработчиков больше, чем это отражено в результатах опроса. Согласно Quantcast, около 12% читателей Stack Overflow принадлежат к женскому полу (но мы не очень активно следим за гендерным портретом участников). Также, по нашим сведениям, в данном исследовании были недостаточно представлены страны с более высоким процентом женщин среди разработчиков, например, азиатские страны: Южная Корея, Индия, Китай.
Итак, не будем приукрашивать действительность: среди разработчиков намного больше мужчин, чем женщин. Сводная статистика этого года практически совпадает с [прошлогодней](https://stackoverflow.com/research/developer-survey-2015#profile-gender).

#### Популярность профессий среди женщин

[image: Women occupations]

Женщины более охотно выбирают профессию дизайнера и с большей вероятностью, чем мужчины, становятся разработчиками программ машинного обучения. Кроме того, женщины часто становятся разработчиками в области тестирования программного обеспечения. Как мужчины, так и женщины в равной степени часто занимают руководящие должности.

#### Зависимость опыта от пола

[image: Experience Global]

[image: North America]

[image: South Asia]

Как можно видеть, опыт работы распределился неравномерно в зависимости от места проживания и пола.

#### Распределение пола по возрастным когортам

[image: Women age]

[image: Men age]

Среди всех респондентов 6% были женщины и еще меньший процент в возрастных группах от 30 до 40 и от 40 до 50 лет. Гендерное неравенство в IT-отрасли наблюдается в разной степени выраженности во всех возрастных когортах.

Не можем утверждать, что знаем, как сократить гендерное неравенство в IT-отрасли, но думаем, что ознакомление общественности с этим явлением – эффективный шаг в сторону расширения диалога по этому вопросу. Именно поэтому примерно через месяц мы выложим полные результаты нашего исследования, чтобы вы проанализировали ситуацию самостоятельно; следите за нашими публикациями в [Twitter](https://twitter.com/stackoverflow).

### VII. Многообразие

#### Для кого важно многообразие в коллективе?

[image: Diversity]

<sub>На основе 42 156 ответов</sub>

В целом, около 73% респондентов отметили важность многообразия в коллективе. 41% разработчиков ответили, что многообразный коллектив представляет собой *особую* важность. И большее число разработчиков, влияющих на процесс найма новых сотрудников (по сравнению с разработчиками, которые такого влияния не оказывают), убеждены в важности присутствия в коллективе как мужчин, так и женщин.

В этом году к нам поступали замечания, что кроме вопросов о гендерном неравенстве мы должны задавать вопросы и о неравенстве национальном. Какие еще вопросы, по вашему мнению, мы должны включить в анкету? [Поделитесь вашими соображениями!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319221/what-else-should-we-ask-developers)

### VIII. Образование

- 69.1% Самообразование
- 43.9% Обучение на рабочем месте
- 34.8% Бакалавр (B.S.) компьютерных (или околокомпьютерных) наук
- 25.5% Онлайн-курсы
- 19.7% Магистр компьютерных (или околокомпьютерных) наук
- 19.2% Курс компьютерных (или околокомпьютерных) наук в колледже
- 8.5% Бакалавр (B.A.) компьютерных (или околокомпьютерных) наук
- 7.2% Программа отраслевой сертификации
- 6.5% Программа-интенсив полного дня (напр., Bootcamp)
- 4.1% Программа неполного дня (напр., вечерняя школа)
- 3.7% Другое
- 2.1% Доктор (PhD) компьютерных (или околокомпьютерных) наук
- 1.2% Менторство

<sub>На основе 40 183 ответов от разработчиков не являющимися студентами</sub>

69% всех разработчиков сообщили, что хоть немного занимались самообразованием (13% респондентов во всем мире ответили, что они полностью самоучки). 43% разработчиков имеют степень бакалавра (B.A. или B. S.) компьютерных и околокомпьютерных наук. 2% разработчиков имеют кандидатскую или докторскую степень (PhD).

Answer (score 1):

> ## Технология
>
> Средства и технологии отрасли.

### I. Самые популярные технологии

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Большинство предпочитает JavaScript другим языкам программирования. Похоже, PHP теряет свои позиции – наряду с ростом популярности Node и Angular.

#### Самые популярные технологии – Другое

[image: Used tech]

[image: Wanted tech]

Delphi оказался языком, который чаще всего вписывали пользователи в поле «Другое», в то время как TypeScript дописывали в качестве языка, который хотелось бы использовать (да-да, OCaml, мы вас заметили).

### II. Самые любимые, нелюбимые и нужные технологии

[image: Loved]

[image: Dreaded]

[image: Wanted]

Уже второй год подряд Rust, Swift и Go попали в пятерку самых любимых языков программирования. VB возглавляет список самых ужасных технологий – если бы он исчез с лица земли, никто не стал бы его оплакивать. Программисты, ведущие разработку на Android, Node и Angular, продолжат использовать их и дальше.

### III. Самые популярные технологии на Stack Overflow

[image: Top SO tags]

50 000 респондентов – это много. 40 миллионов респондентов – ещё больше. Каждый месяц 40 миллионов пользователей заходят на Stack Overflow и оставляют ответы на вопросы об используемых технологиях. В январе 2016 года пользователи выразили своё мнение 2,2 млн. раз (1,7 млн. в виде голосов за тот или иной вопрос, плюс 540 тыс. анонимных голосов). В июне 2015 года метка JavaScript опередила метку Java и стала самой популярной на Stack Overflow. В декабре Swift «победил» Objective-C. Вы можете сами проанализировать пользовательское мнение пользуясь [нашим обозревателем открытых данных](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/440749/anonymous-feedback-votes-over-time-on-a-specific-tag?tagname=ocaml&ref=survey-2016#graph).

### IV. Технологии набирающие популярность на Stack Overflow

[image: Stack Overflow Winners]

[image: Stack Overflow Losers]

<sub>*Проценты показывают изменения в доле голосов участников Stack Overflow в период с января 2015 г. по январь 2016 г.*</sub>

Новые технологии веб-разработки наподобие React, Node.js и AngularJS используются всё чаще. Та же ситуация наблюдается со Swift, отбирающем у Objective C его долю рынка. Разработчики, похоже, теряют интерес к CoffeeScript, Haskell и Windows Phone. И хотя исследования показало, что многие хотели бы уйти от Visual Basic и Wordpress, эти технологии пока не теряют своих позиций.

### V. Наиболее оплачиваемые технологий

[image: Top Paying in US]

[image: Top Paying Worldwide]

Да будет дождь! Облачные технологии – а также технологии, используемые в сфере финансов,– приносят немалый доход. Spark, Scala, Cassandra и F# возглавляют список самых рентабельных технологий (в этом году он очень напоминает [прошлогодний рейтинг](https://stackoverflow.com/research/developer-survey-2015#work-complang)).

А вы не думали поискать [работу на Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?searchTerm=spark&ref=survey-2016)?

#### Наиболее оплачиваемые специализации

[image: Full Stack Paying]

[image: Front End Paying]

[image: Math Paying]

[image: Mobile Paying]

Разработчики полного цикла, владеющие JavaScript и пишущие для «облака» или работающие с React или Redis, получают больше, чем коллеги.

Разработчики пользовательского интерфейса, знающие JavaScript и React, Node или Angular, также получают более щедрое вознаграждение, чем их коллеги, не владеющие этими технологиями.

Программисты с математическим образованием (включая специалистов в области обработки данных и машинного обучения), владеющие Scala, Spark или Hadoop получают большую зарплату, чем коллеги. Специалисты по Python и R получают примерно столько же, хотя число программистов с математическим образованием, владеющих Python, в два раза больше.

Разработчики мобильных приложений, знающие экосистему iOS, зарабатывают в среднем на $10000 в год больше, чем разработчики под Android.

### VI. Смежные технологии

[image: 2 Tech]

[image: 4 Tech]

Среднестатистический разработчик регулярно пользуется 4-5 основными языками программирования, платформами и технологиями. Самой популярной комбинацией из двух технологий является тандем JavaScript и SQL, из трех – JavaScript, PHP и SQL.

### Используемые технологии в зависимости от специализации

[image: Full-Stack]

[image: Front-End]

[image: Back-End]

[image: Data Scientists]

Разработчики полного цикла чаще пишут на PHP, чем на других языках разработки серверных приложений (сразу за PHP в рейтинге следуют C#и Java).

JavaScript такой популярный, что попал в три самые часто упоминаемые комбинации технологий, используемых разработчиками серверных приложений. Это наталкивает на мысль, что многие разработчики серверных приложений – это, на самом деле, маскирующиеся разработчики полного цикла. Наша внутренняя статистика свидетельствует о том, что около 60% профессиональных разработчиков по существу работают над полным циклом.

63% специалистов по обработке данных используют Python, 44% используют R, а 27% используют оба этих языка (14% используют Python, R и SQL).

### VII. Среда разработки

[image: IDE]

В прошлом году мы задавали вам вопрос о [текстовых редакторах](https://stackoverflow.com/research/developer-survey-2015#tech-editor). В этом году мы пошли дальше и задали вопрос обо всех основных IDE, текстовых редакторах и других средствах кодирования, не поддающихся категоризации. Среднестатистический разработчик использует 2-3 среды разработки. Варианты, добавленные респондентами самостоятельно, включали WebStorm (1.6%), brackets (.8%), QT Creator (.7%) и Delphi (.4%).

### Среды разработки в зависимости от специализации

[image: IDE Full-Stack]

[image: IDE Data Scientist]

[image: IDE Students]

Специалисты по обработке данных пользуются Vim и Notepad++. Разработчики полного цикла используют Visual Studio и Sublime. Студенты работают в Notepad++ и Visual Studio.

### VII. Операционная система

[image: OS 2016]

В минувшем году Mac опередил семейство Linux, выйдя на вторую позицию в рейтинге самых популярных ОС среди разработчиков. В текущем году этот тренд только подтвердился. При сохранении существующей тенденции, к опросу следующего года Windows будет использовать на 50% меньше программистов, чем в этом году.

Если говорить о Linux, то здесь лидирует Ubuntu с 12,3% от всего рынка ОС для программистов. Fedora, Mint и Debian набрали 1.4%, 1.7% и 1.9%, соответственно.

Answer (score 1):

> ## Сообщество
>
> Разработчики, которые помогают своим коллегам творить.

### I. Частота посещений

[image: SO Visits]

Более половины ответивших сообщили, что посещают Stack Overflow по нескольку раз в день, а 78% респондентов сообщили, что заходят ежедневно.

### II. Мотивация

[image: Motivation]

Подавляющее большинство разработчиков используют Stack Overflow для получения помощи по работе. Большинство также используют Stack Overflow потому, что любят учиться новому.

### III. Вопросы и ответы

[image: Asking & Answering]

С момента запуска Stack Overflow в 2009-м году было задано 12,3 млн. вопросов и дано 18,4 млн. ответов.

В 2015 г. на Stack Overflow было задано 2,7 млн. вопросов и опубликовано 3,2 млн. ответов.

Респонденты нашего анкетирования принимали более активное участие в работе сообщества. Более 27000 респондентов сообщили нам данные своих учетных записей. Мы проанализировали их статистику: ими было задано 383445 вопросов и дано 2804051 ответов. Миллионам коллег эти вопросы и ответы помогли в работе (и вы можете быть одним из них).

#### Репуатция

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Репутация – это не просто виртуальные баллы: это показатель того, скольким пользователям вы помогли (что ж, это и виртуальные баллы тоже, конечно…).

Если вы принадлежите к 96% разработчиков, которые получают помощь сообщества хотя бы раз в месяц и хотели бы выразить за это благодарность, начните с того, что [зарегистрируйтесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/signup?ssrc=survey-2016&ref=survey-2016)!